# How to bind boost::iterator_range of Iterator class using Boost Python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I'm new to boost::python so please forgive me if I'm asking a stupid question. I'm trying to bind a Container and an Iterator classes to Python. My container is like a matrix of items where each row can be accessed through a method called `Iterate()` which returns a `boost::iterator_range` of my `Iterator`. `Iterator` has implemented various operators: ++, !=, == and * operator to get an `Accessor` instance which can access to the item's data. The code is like following:

```
class Accessor {
  ItemValue get_value_item() {...}
};

class Iterator {
 public:
  Iterator &operator++();
  Iterator &operator++(int);
  bool operator==(...);
  bool operator!=(...);
  Accessor operator*() const {
    return Accessor(idx_);
  }
 private:
  int idx_;
};

class Container {
 public:
  boost::iterator_range<Iterator> Iterate(int id) {
     return boost::iterator_range<Iterator>(Iterator(...), Iterator(...));
  }
};
```

I expect the Python code to be like:

```
container = Container()
def func(id):
  for record in container.Iterate(id):
    print(record.get_accessor.get_value_item())
```

I'm only able to bind the `Container` class and get stuck when binding `Iterator` class because I have no idea how to bind those operator to Python. I'm not familiar with Python so I don't quite understand how iterating work in Python.

How should I expose the `Iterator` and `boost::iterator_range` to Python?